# Not able to get the Zoom/Pan and States name appear in India Map - D3?

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, d3.js

I am new to *D3.js*. However after being practiced the examples of [this](http://christopheviau.com/d3_tutorial/) site, I tried to play ahead with Mr.John Coogan's map given [here](https://gist.github.com/JohnCoogan/1531818). The output that I found in his site is as under

[image]

But when I am trying to do the same thing by placing his *.js,css,*.json and index.html in plunker it is coming as

[image]

**Problems**

a) No States are getting displayed

b) Zoom and Pan is not working

***In another word, at this point of time I am looking only for the Indian map to work exactly as the example shown by Mr. Coogan.***

What needs to be done for this?

Comment: Plunker:  http://plnkr.co/edit/PLbl3TJFmaaLfM5sI4g9?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

Here's the working plunk: http://plnkr.co/1EqpIFecwJmkbvypTyQD?p=preview

You needed to uncomment this line:

```
.call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw))
```

on line 40 of the index.html in your plunk, and then zoom and pan will work.

The **state colors (based on wealth)** are not showing because of various, more complex errors. The error shown in the console (`svg is not defined` referencing line 78) is just the start (you need to replace `svg` with `india`, which *is* defined).

In fact the [whole original gist](http://bl.ocks.org/JohnCoogan/1531818) your example is based on is really just a work in progress, but most of the answers for how to fix it can be found in [this thread from the google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/MW0mKSxn5pY), from Mike Bostock himself.

Essentially, the json data loads asynchronously, so need to be loaded in series.

```
// load the two JSON files in series
d3.json("states.json", function(states) {
    d3.json("wealth.json", function(wealthdata) {
        ...
    });
});
```

Then you can just apend the relevant colorbrewer CSS class when you first create each `path`:

```
india.selectAll("path")

    .data(states.features)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", path)

    .attr("class", function(d) {
        return "q" + quantize(wealthdata[d.id]) + "-9";
     })

    .attr("d", path);
```

But you also need to define the `quantize` scale, range...:

```
var quantize = d3.scale.quantize()
```

.range(d3.range(9));

... and domain (which you can only do once the data has been loaded:

```
quantize.domain([0, d3.max(d3.values(wealthdata))]);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Could please let me know how can I display the state names in the map from states.json . Basically question (a)

Comment: This should help: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/uAWkwnuNQ3Q. You'll need to calculate the centre of each shape and then `.append("svg:text")` labels to the SVG with the appropriate `x` and `y`